# Dwolla payment button: Is the redirect after successful checkout prevented until callback/notification occurs?

Tags: php, payment-gateway, payment, dwolla

The reason I'm asking this is b/c the page that gets showed to the user after successful purchase typically differs depending on whether or the purchase was actually made.

So one typically **MUST** know whether or not the purchase was successful before the redirect occurs.

If Dwolla's callback and/or webhook notification isn't guarenteed to arrive first, does anyone have suggestions for how to code (in PHP) the necessary polling/waiting at the redirect URL to allow for the notification to be processed first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Dwolla:

"we never wait for webhooks"

"we do, however, wait for the CALLBACK (I assume they mean the one called ["Payment Callback"](https://www.dwolla.com/applications)) before we redirect the user back to your site".